# Visual Studio "Unable to copy file" during publishing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I keep getting this error during the publishing of my VS 2019 C# win forms project

```
Unable to copy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.8.0.dll" to "bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Database Client_2_0_0_47\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.8.0.dll". Could not find a part of the path 'bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Database Client_2_0_0_47\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.8.0.dll'.  Database Client
```

This also happens with 4 other DLL's with some being from VS 2019 itself and some from NuGet packages

This has only started happening recently so I'm unsure whether this is an issue with VS 2019 as no fundamental code has been changed and the only thing that has is some logos on a few .rdlc documents (Microsoft Report Viewer).

I'm running VS 2019 Community on version 16.11.4 with only .Net Desktop development, Office/Sharepoint development and a few individual packages installed.

I've looked around and can only seem to find people having issues with the .exes themselves due to them still being open however this is not the case for me as I have checked and there are no background processes like devenv.

What's strange is both the Debug and Release build fine with no issues whatsoever.

I've also tried deleting the \bin and \obj folders to no avail.

Below are some images of my settings that involve publishing

[Publishing Main Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq4mh.png)

[Prerequisites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vXGa.png)

[Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOXjQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please a screenshot of your publishing settings alongside supporting text? Reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would also be a great way to start, if you haven't read it yet

Comment: Being unable to copy a file to a relative path suggests that the "current directory" is not as expected. Perhaps change the target to be an absolute path. Perhaps find some way of getting the publishing system to print out the current directory.

Comment: If you download procmon.exe from Microsoft you can get a view over what file accesses are being carried out by the system, and check for any paths that don't look like what you'd expect.

Comment: Try to start a new project with similar structure and same package to see if it properly works. If it does, then add any missing file and replace your original solution with the new one. Or alternatively, compare settings of both projects/solutions.

Comment: If a problem is recent, then usually the best thing to do is to compare with an older revision that works (obviously, if you professtionnal development, you use `git` or some other source control).

Comment: 116 characters in that relative path, getting a bit beefy.  You may have to move the project closer to the root to avoid exceeding MAX_PATH.

Comment: @HansPassant Seems like this was the solution thanks a lot for solving my issue. All I had to do was move out of the default source folder in my user files to the C:\ drive and it published instantly.

Answer (score 8):

It seems the solution to this problem, as @HansPassant commented, was to shorten the build path as it was exceeding the MAX_PATH variable.

Once my project was moved from the default C:\Users\Drew\source\repos\ to just the C:\ drive my project was able to publish successfully.

Comment: Phew, this answer was a life saver!  thanks...